# How to set span value inside of anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have anchor tag in which some class bind dynamically on page load, I need to change the value of span tag inside anchor tag below is my code:

```
<a id="aView" km-button km-state-active" data-badge="0" href="#view" data- icon="globe" data-role="tab">
    <span class="km-icon km-globe"></span>
    <span class="km-badge">0</span>
    <span class="km-text">view</span>
</a>
```

I need to change "km-badge" value using JavaScript or jQuery need help

Comment: you can use something like this in Jquery

$('#aView .km-badge').text("2")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#aView .km-badge").text("blablabla");
```

#### 2nd:

```
var el = $("#aView .km-badge"); // define variable that points to DOM object
el.removeClass("km-badge"); // remove class from object
el.text("blablabla"); // change attribute "text" of object
el.addClass("km-badge"); // add class to object
```

Comment: @thanks it worked for me, how i can remove ".km-badge" class, i need to remove class before initial,after initialize i need to add ".km-badge"

Comment: I've changed answer

Comment: Now just small issue,how to add the class back to same span

Comment: I appended this to answer after "2nd:"

Comment: is it possible to add css display none to el

Comment: el.css("display", "none");

Answer (score 0):

with javascript you can do,

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("aView").innerHTML = "writetexthere";
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: and if you wanna remove class

Comment: use class list ELEMENT.classList.remove("CLASS_NAME");